# How to configure log4j.properties in external folder for a web application in tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, classpath, tomcat5.5

Please help how to handle the below scenario.

**Current Web app :**
<sub>I have placed log4j.propertes in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of webapp.</sub>

**Wanted to achieve :**

<sub>Place log4j.properties in an external location and refer from my web application, so that i can modify the log location when ever i want without re building the war.</sub>

`$CATALINA_HOME/propdirwebapp1/log4j.properties
$CATALINA_HOME/propdirwebapp2/log4j.properties`

<sub>If i have multiple applications deployed please suggest the solution. If only one application is deployed on server please suggest the solution</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case in `web.xml` I added `Log4jConfigListener` and it worked. `log4jRefreshInterval` is optional here.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/<your-path-here>/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <!-- Refresh log4j configuration every 5 minutes. -->
    <param-value>300000</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to rebuild war file, instead of that just directly modify log4j.properties and restart the tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as long a you have war in webapps folder no matter if you change the path in exploded folder it is going to override on tomcat restart , i think need to be handled in some other way.

Comment: No, Tomcat does not change the exploded folder on restart, however, I agree that modifications to the exploded folder is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a directory to shared.loader property in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties.

```
shared.loader=conf/myapp/
```

Then put the log4j.properties in this directory.

But there are two constraints.

1) If there is a log4j.properties file in the `WEBINF/classes` that one will get loaded first

2) This directory gets shared by all webapps so there can only by one log4j.properties file for all webapps.

Comment: This looks cool but the bottleneck is all the webapps will share same log4j. probably need to configure the log based on package and push the log to specific log file would solve the problem. :) Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I like my attempt, it just deals with log levels for different war applications.

Place a custom properties file in conf, for example

```
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/my.properties
```

Create entries like

```
myapp.loglevel = INFO
myapp2.loglevel = DEBUG
```

Read the props per request, for example

```
myProps = new Properties();
myProps.load(new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf/my.properties")));
```

Read and use the property like for example in a servlet at the beginning of a request

```
String myLoglevel = (String)myProps.get("myapp.loglevel");
LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.toLevel(myLoglevel));
```

We're using slf4j-log4j12 and I've read there's no LogManager in log4j2, but I'm sure this mechanism could be applied to log4j2, too.